Json Path - get all but last element of an array
I have a JSON array:
[
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4
]

I want to create a Json Path expression that returns all but the last element of the array, i.e. the result is:
[
    1,
    2,
    3
]

There are lots of examples of first N elements and last N elements, but not the above.  I can't work out the syntax.
I am using System.Text.Json with JsonPath.Net (https://www.nuget.org/packages/JsonPath.Net/)

JsonPath.NET implements RFC 9535, and RFC 9535 includes the Array Slice Selector [start:end:step].  When start or end are negative, they are interpreted as offsets from the array end:

Slice expression parameters start and end are not directly usable as slice bounds and must first be normalized. Normalization for this purpose is defined as:
FUNCTION Normalize(i, len):
  IF i >= 0 THEN
    RETURN i
  ELSE
    RETURN len + i
  END IF


Thus "$[0:-1]" should return all but the last element of the array, and JsonPath.NET does seem to implement this correctly:
var jsonArray = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4} )!.AsArray();

var path = JsonPath.Parse("$[0:-1]");
var results = path.Evaluate(jsonArray);

var newArray = JsonSerializer.SerializeToNode(results.Matches.Select(m => m.Value))!.AsArray(); // [1,2,3]

Assert.That(new int [] { 1, 2, 3 }.SequenceEqual(newArray.Deserialize<int []>()!)); // PASSES

Demo fiddle here.

Syntax to support your use case doesn't exist in the JSON Path spec.  You need a way to get the index of the current value.
We have an open issue for a proposal to add that in a potential next version, https://github.com/ietf-wg-jsonpath/draft-ietf-jsonpath-base/issues/516.
The other difficult part in this particular case is that you'd need to get the length of the parent array. Again, there's not a syntax for that.

Assuming you built custom functions key() and parent(), and you enabled math operations (in the parsing options), you might be able to do something like this:
$[key(@)<length(parent(@))-1]


I hesitate to correct you since you are the JsonPath.Net author, but JsonPath.Parse("$[0:-1]") seems to work.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/GFyTSL.

@gregsdennis, in my code, with JsonPath.Net, @.length of course doesn't work, but $[:-1] does.  If it's a mistake that $[:-1] works, please don't fix it!!!

Nope, that's perfectly valid.  0:-1 is a valid slice.  It starts from the first, and ends just before the last.  That's a nice way to do it!
